# Don't allow space as a last character

Tags: python, regex

I have this Python regex: `[A-Za-z0-9_\s]+`

How can I set it up so that it allows spaces, but doesn't allow spaces as the last character.

Given the string

```
"Monthly Report Aug 27th 2013 - New York"
```

I'd like it to match

```
"Monthly Report Aug 27th 2013"
```

not

```
"Monthly Report Aug 27th 2013 "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will write it like this:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*
```

Note: if you don't use the `re.LOCALE` or `re.UNICODE` options, the pattern can be shorten to:

```
\w+(?:\s+\w+)*
```

Answer (score 1):

Python supports the "non-whitespace" wildcard: `\S` (capitalized wild cards tend to be the opposite of lowercase.) So you could use something like this:

```
r'[A-Za-z0-9_\s]+\S$'
```

Comment: The anchor (`$`) forces the match to extend all the way to the end of the string, which is not what he wants.  And if you ditch the anchor while leaving the `\S` at the end, it matches up to (and including) the hyphen; again, not what's wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [A-Za-z0-9_\s]+[A-Za-z0-9_]. You just add an extra character on the end of the regular expression that doesn't match a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
([\w\s]+)\s
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oU7vL2/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-28]  `Monthly Report Aug 27th 2013`
```